# How to add permission pointer for pointers in array field?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

In a table called Project, I have a column "users" that is a n-n relation with the User table. I want to give every user that is related, permission to read and update its own project object. Unfortunately I can't make this work via the following code:

```
const projectACL: Parse.Schema.CLP = {
  readUserFields: ["users"],
  writeUserFields: ["users"]
  }
};
```

The following error is thrown:

> ParseError: 'users' is not a valid column for class level pointer permissions readUserFields

In the source code one can see there is a check if the argument of readUserFields and writeUserFields is a pointer OR an array, but "users" is a relation (not an array).

Is what I want even possible? I'm sorry I couldn't find any documentation or examples on this, so I would much appreciate an example of how to make it work.

Comment: You can add controls to beforeFind and beforeSave triggers for Project class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the source code: it checks if the value is an array of column names, and if each listed column contains pointers to users, which is what you call a relation with the user table.
So normally it should work if the `users` field is set like this, with `user` being an instance of `Parse.User`:

```
project.set('users', user);
```

The code which checks the fields is [there](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/b754d51e8e85cf74912683208fb1c56650e8b313/src/Controllers/SchemaController.js#L184) and we can see an implementation example [there](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/9ea355b4635226ae4da17c8cc5fb0321e3fdec5e/spec/PointerPermissions.spec.js#L25).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use  **useMasterKey**

```
 return user.save(null, {
    useMasterKey: true
  })
```